# In android how to set moving image?

Tags: android

I use ListView for viewing different charts but now i want to see those charts just swipe right to left. Like  the image switcher.How to set navigation to the next chart.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question, I could not understand at all. In order to get response quicker explain your self clearly, share some link such as "link of something you have seen and you are pursuing to build similar stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You can set image object and add animation to that.
Create a hashmap where you can set which type of animation do you want over the image.
While retrieving you can give image and get the animation type. and you can put that animation type to your image.

pseudo code:

```
HashMap animationdetails = new Hashmap();
animationdetails.put(image, animationtype);
```

You maybe want to read [How to do animation in android](http://knowledgefolders.com/akc/display?url=displaynoteimpurl&ownerUserId=satya&reportId=2895), too.